# Rails 4 scope includes with nested association hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Within Rails 3 I had been using the following includes scope (defined in a module) which worked fine.

```
base.send :scope, :with_includes, { :include => {:questions => [:answers, :question_group, {:dependency => :dependency_conditions}]}}
```

This no longer works within Rails 4, so I have tried converting it to the now preferred lambda method as follows.

```
base.send :scope, :with_includes, -> { includes(:questions => [:answers, :question_group, {:dependency => :dependency_conditions}]) }
```

This just raises an exception `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `base.includes(...)` inside the lambda.

Basically, the `self` captured in your lambda is not your record's class : it's where the `scope` is `send`(t).